# simple html dom php curl error cannot grab text i need

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, curl

i am using the following code in my cript to grab a part of source code i need 
but it get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ')' in /home/cyberhos/public_html/CH/tes.php on line 151

simple_html_dom.php is already issued in my script elswhere

```
        if (isset($_POST['mp'], $_POST['delim'], $_POST['submit'])) {
        $mps = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['mp']);

        // Create an array to store results
        $result_data = array();

        // Iterate over requests
        foreach ($mps as $mp) {
            $mp = explode($_POST['delim'], $mp);

            // Store the account details in variables
            list($email, $password) = $mp;

            // Get HTML data
            $html_string = checkmail($email, $password);
            $html = str_get_html($html_string);
            $body = $html->find('div[id="welcome_text"]);
            // Prepare a reusable string
            $result_string = "Checked " . $email .  " : " . $password . " is ";

            // Append necessary word to it
            if ($html>welcome_text === "Welcome to Tesco.com. We hope that you enjoy your visit.") {
                $result_string .= "LIVE";
            } else {
                $result_string .= "DEAD";
            }
```

how can i fix this error is there any way that i can fix this error so my script works properly

heres the part of source code i am trying to get

```
<div id="welcome_text" class="">
<div class="box">

Welcome to Tesco.com. We hope that you enjoy your visit.
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_lnkLogin" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$lnkLogin','')">Log out</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Single quote `'`  is missing on near line `$body = ...`. You can clearly get this by checking the color difference in your posted code above.

Comment: could u make an edit so i can see what you mean :)

Comment: A typo in line 17: `$body = $html->find('div[id="welcome_text"]`'`);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss `'` in this line edited is

```
 $body = $html->find('div[id="welcome_text"]');
```

your edited code

```
 if (isset($_POST['mp'], $_POST['delim'], $_POST['submit'])) {
    $mps = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['mp']);

    // Create an array to store results
    $result_data = array();

    // Iterate over requests
    foreach ($mps as $mp) {
        $mp = explode($_POST['delim'], $mp);

        // Store the account details in variables
        list($email, $password) = $mp;

        // Get HTML data
        $html_string = checkmail($email, $password);
        $html = str_get_html($html_string);
        $body = $html->find('div[id="welcome_text"]');
        // Prepare a reusable string
        $result_string = "Checked " . $email .  " : " . $password . " is ";

        // Append necessary word to it
        if ($html>welcome_text === "Welcome to Tesco.com. We hope that you enjoy your visit.") {
            $result_string .= "LIVE";
        } else {
            $result_string .= "DEAD";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wicked that that error fixed but its still not doing what i need lol

Comment: thanks bro i will accept that answer as soon as i can problem is its not fetching what i want :/

Comment: i can't test because you use some kind of function that i haven't  in my system like  `str_get_html` check the output of this function it help you for find problem

Comment: for check output use `print_r` or `var_dump`

Comment: send for me I'll be happy to help you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29094/discussion-between-david-tuckwell-and-mohammad-mohsenipur)